# How can I mark a <select> option selected based on an inital value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a screen with a  that has 50+ rows callect TopidID. On that screen I have a 
grid that can potentially have a large number of rows. As an alternative to every row
having a  with many choices I populate my selects with just the one item as below:

```
<td> 
<select title="X" data-clicked="N" data-list="N" id="input_TempRowKey_73" name="rowKey_73" class="select-topic">
   <option value="0307">ABC</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

When a user clicks on any of these row selects for the first time I then change the contents of the select and copy in the many options from the TopidID `<select>`. The code works and the action happens quickly so the user isn't aware that the new options are added.

```
 .on('click', '.select-topic', function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-list') == "N") {
            $(this).attr('data-list', 'Y')
            var topicSelectHtml = $('#TopicID').clone().find("optgroup:first").remove().end().find("option[value$='**']").remove().end().html();
            $(this).html(topicSelectHtml);
            $(this).attr('data-clicked', 'Y')
        }
        return false;
    })
```

However I have a problem. When the user clicks then the new list appears and the original 
value that is selected (in this case ABC) is no longer selected.

Is there a way that I could do the following:

1. Store away the original value in the select ( in this case 0307  and ABC )
2. Copy in the new choices to the new longer list of options and mark as "selected" the one in the list that matches what was there before ( in this case 0307 and ABC)

Here is the format of the TopicID . It's very standard  code:

```
<select id="TopicID">
   <optgroup label="Admin">
      <option value="0000">All Topics</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="X">
      <option value="0307">ABC</option>
      <option value="0308">DEF</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the html markup for the element with `id=TopicID` to the question?

Comment: Thanks. I added this. It's very standard select. Just somehow need to get the initial value, store it, refresh will all the new options and then update the select options to show the selected item. Easy to write here but I'm not sure how to do this in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply actually (your code is harder than what you still need to add):

```
function dropdownlistprocessing () {

    var selectedval = $("#mydropdown").val();

    // now process your dropdownlist

    $("#mydropdown").val(selectedval);
}
```

Edit: as you can see, if you use `.val()` you *get* the selected value. If you pass a value using `.val(foo)`, you will set the select item in the dropdownlist.

**EDIT2**
As per the comments below, I think you want this then?

```
function dropdownlistprocessing () {

    var selectedval = $("#mydropdown_A").val();

    // now process your dropdownlist

    $("#mydropdown_B").val(selectedval);
}
```

Comment: Hello - Thanks for the help but it's not quite what I need. I need to updated the long list that appears for the user to select from. sberry came up with an example jsFiddle. It's close but I have no Go button and everything is started when the user clicks the select drop down. Hope I make sense.

Comment: If I read your question correctly, you need to know how to update a dropdownlist without the currently selected value changing. If you put your code in between mine (where the comment is), you will achieve that goal. However, if the code for adding elements to the dropdownlist is not working, could you please elaborate or show us what you mean? I can see you're trying to inform us fully but there is some piece of information missing as we cannot fully comprehend the intentions. I mean no offense :-)

Comment: Hi, the code for the dropdown list is working good. Where I have a problem is that when the dropdown list appear the first item is always the one highlighted in the list. What I need is for that dropdown list that appears to have the item that was in my select box before I clicked highlighted. Hope that makes sense. It's difficult for me to describe. Thanks.

Comment: Ah so you mean you want the selected value frop dropdownlist A to be selected in dropdownlist B (after the items have been added from A to B)? In that case, check my revised answer above